# Does the Crystal report runtime basic for Visual Studio support assigning a printer?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I've been using the Crystal report basic runtime 2008 (10.5) for over 3 years. I upgraded to their latest developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio (13) a year or so ago, and installed the service pack 2. But I found that setting PrintOptions.PrinterName on the report document had no effect if the report already had a printer name. This is outlined [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2099449) and [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3292416).

```
// This is the old and reliable way - didn't work for version 13
Settings = new PrinterSettings();
Settings.PrinterName = "HP Printer";
_report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Settings.PrinterName;
// for version 13 you have to assign the printer settings
if(_report.PrintOptions.PrinterName != Settings.PrinterName)
    _report.PrintToPrinter(Settings, new PageSettings(), false);
```

The only way to change the printer name at runtime was to create a new printer settings object and assign the required printer name. The problem with this is that it added over a minute to the most basic print jobs. I had to perform a difficult rollback to version 10.5 which I still use with visual studio 2013.

Has anyone had any experience with the updated service packs (9 or 10)?

Their [documentation](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) for fixed bugs do not mention this issue as having been fixed. I'm considering the upgrade again to address some missing features from version 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that [SAP will not be fixing anything to do with PrintToPrinter](http://scn.sap.com/message/11017128#11017128)!

The problem (bug) with printer assignments still persists, what has changed is that it no longer takes 2-3 minutes to assign the entire printer settings object. Additionally, there are better ways to print now as suggested by SAP.

So, I try to avoid it by only using the PrintToPrinter overload that accepts PrinterSettings, if the printer name assignment doesn't "take":

```
// Attempt to assign just the printer name
_report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = Settings.PrinterName;

// Check if the name change worked, if not, PrintToPrinter with the settings object
if(_report.PrintOptions.PrinterName != Settings.PrinterName)
    _report.PrintToPrinter(Settings, new PageSettings(), false); // print with settings
else
    _report.PrintToPrinter(Settings.Copies, Settings.Collate, 0, 0); // print with printer name
```

SAP suggests using _report.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(options) instead of _report.PrintToPrinter(...). My repeatable tests have shown that this method is at least three times faster, in spooling the job! (I used stopWatch, and printed the same 18 page static report over and over again. PrintToPrinter takes around 9 seconds each time to spool, while the method below averages at 3 seconds)

```
// Create the printer options
var options = new PrintReportOptions
{
    PrinterName = Settings.PrinterName,
    Collated = Settings.Collate,
    NumberOfCopies = Settings.Copies,
    JobTitle = _report.Name,       
};
// pass the options to the print method
_report.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(options);
```